# How to change the value of a tensor which is not a tf.Variable in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, variable-assignment

I know that there is a `tf.assign` function in TensorFlow, but this function is mainly aimed at mutable tensor (`tf.Variable`). How to modify the value of the tensor? For example, the following code,

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32, 32, 3])

conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(X, filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same',name='conv1')
relu1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)

conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(relu1, filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same',name='conv2')
relu2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(u'conv2/Conv2D:0')
feature_map = tf.reduce_mean(tensor[:,:,:,24])

image = np.random.uniform(size=(1,32,32,3))
sess.run([feature_map], feed_dict={X: image})
```

How to modify the value of `feature_map` and do not affect its derivation?

More specifically, when I change the value of `feature_map`, it does not affect its derivation process. 
For example, `y = a^2`, `y'= 2a`, I just need to change `a = 1` to `a = 2`.

`Other_op = tf.gradients(feature_map, X)`

Different `feature_map` would achieve the different values, but it does not destroy the graph structures of operation.

Comment: Still not quite clear. Perhaps it is to others. Changing the fed in value will affect the tensors that use that as an input. So I would expect `y` (in `y = a^2`) to change if `a` was fed in. Why would you not want those to be affected? I think you may have to change your graph.

Comment: Just like a cross entropy loss. I need to normalize the loss value, it's a tensor. So I want to modify value, and it also could back propagate.

Comment: Might start to make sense now. You could provide an example of that. It sounds like you are asking to replace the loss value when in fact you it might be better to allow a placeholder/variable used in the loss calculation to be passed in. (I didn't pay so much attention when you suggested `tf.gradient` as the operation) Other people might have better ideas.

Comment: The fed in value can affect the tensors, but it is strange that this change does not affect the value of the derivation. Anyway, thanks for the discussion with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `feature_map` doesn't have a value as it's an operation. Therefore you can't change it's value as such. What you can do, is pass another value in as part of the `feed_dict` parameter of `session.run`.

So for example if your feature_map is followed by an operation like this:

```
other_op = tf.gradient(feature_map, X)
```

Then you can change the value passed in to that op (`gradient` in this case) via `feed_dict` like so:

```
session.run(other_op, feed_dict={feature_map: <new value>})
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Is it possible to be more clear how to use the `feed_dict` method to pass another value. And will the new value affect its derivation? just like `tf.gradient(feature_map, X)`

Comment: Yes, I added an example for that

Comment: But using `feed_dict` pass values, `feature_map` needs to be a `tf.placeholder`.  it won't propagate. Sadly, it is useless to try this method.

Comment: A `tf.placeholder` has to be fed via `feed_dict`. But other tensors can also be fed that way.

Comment: Yes! you are right! but in this case, I found `session.run(other_op, feed_dict={X:image, feature_map: <new value>})` and `session.run(other_op, feed_dict={X:image, feature_map: <new value>})` have the same value. That's what I said did not work

Comment: Okay, I have to admit I am not sure what you actually want to achieve then. (BTW both of the expression in your last comment look the same to me). Perhaps best to post a new question with want you actually want to achieve in the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The problem has been trimmed. I hope to make it clear this time.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. A tensor is the output of `tf.Operation`. From [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor):

> A Tensor is a symbolic handle to one of the outputs of an `Operation`. It does not hold the values of that operation's output, but instead provides a means of computing those values in a TensorFlow `tf.Session`.

So you can't change its value independently.

Comment: Thanks for your instructions. Is there any other way to achieve the results I described?

Comment: You can run the subsequent ops and pass your own value of `feature_map`. So that other ops will *think* that `feature_map` has that value. But it won't propagate through `feature_map`. If that's enough, try `sess.run(..., feed_dict={feature_map: ...})`

Comment: Maybe I really need to think of other ways. I want to change the value of an _op_, but does not affect its _graph_